# Publish android app on amazon appstore

Tags: android, app-store, amazon-appstore

I published some apps on amazon appstore. After amazon reviewed those apps, the app status change to approved, but I don't know how to make my apps to go live. Do I have to do anything to change the status to live or it's automatically?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is automatic.

In your app profile when you were setting it up, you chose the date to publish, if you left this as default your app should be live as soon as Amazon accept it!

Comment: Amazon approved my app over 4 days ago, yet it is still not live. And I specified no date to make it live. I am not sure this answer is correct. I tried contacting Amazon with no response.